# additional margin shows up on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I just made a website using both materializecss and bootstrap platform.(I know this is a bad idea, but worked for me)
I have a problem on mobile view. when I reduce the viewport, it seems a margin shows up aside the whole body part and I have no idea what is this about!
I give 2 screenshots and the website addresses to look it up.
* if you explain what parts of code you need to look, I present it.
[example screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70SN.png)
and this [example screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyxDy.jpg).
here are the website addresses:
[www.shariffoundation.ir/prototypetest](https://www.shariffoundation.ir/prototypetest) and
[www.petrobavar.ir](https://www.petrobavar.ir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this link - www.shariffoundation.ir/prototypetest (The issue seems to be from the animations in your footer element, so I'd say use {overflow:hidden} for the footer area to help fix this.

For the second link - I'd say to user overflow:hidden on the id "responsiblity"
so #responsiblity{overflow:hidden}

Comment: actually it worked! just in one example(petrobavar.ir) there is still a bit margin, but the main problem solved. thank you very much.
can I ask you how did you understand the problem?

Comment: Glad it helped. I had to look at the layout, I noticed some changes as I scrolled down and noted it happened exactly when the animations faded in, I figured you would need to hide the overflow then.